# Laravel eloquent hasmany->hasmany

Tags: laravel, eloquent

it is possible to get all details (user, posts, postimages) within one collection / json?

user->hasmany(posts)
post->hasmany(postimage)

user:
id | name

post:
id | user_id | text

postimage:
id | post_id | imgpath

user model:

```
 public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\posts')->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
    }
```

posts model:

```
public function images(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\postsimages');
    }
```

get all posts from user works fine:

```
$myposts = users::find(Auth::user()->id)->posts;
```

i'm able to get all images from a post within a loop

```
foreach($myposts as $mypost) {
    $postimages = $mypost->images;
}
```

what i want is to get all posts, images without the loop e.g

```
$myposts = users::find(Auth::user()->id)->posts->images
```

thanks

Comment: try : $myposts = users::find(Auth::user()->id)->posts()->images;

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$images

Comment: Try `$myposts = users::find(Auth::user()->id)->posts->with('images')->get()`

Comment: @Rifki Auth::user() already an UserObject. No reason to find model again. ```Auth::user()->posts...```

Comment: @xdevnull Yeah I was thinking the same, but I just copied OP code and add  additional code that might work as OP expected.

Comment: Okay so as @xdevnull said you no need to find user again as `Auth::user()` is already an User model. Try `Auth::user()->posts->with('images')->get()`

Comment: @Rifki See huulk answer. Correct one :)

Comment: @xdevnull I thought that OP want to load `posts` images immediately without having to call `$post->images` within a loop not to get images of user through his posts. I could be wrong but let's OP clarify this.

Comment: @Rifki correct, i tried huuuks answer and get only the images of the users posts! what i want is to get from user X all posts (all data) and images (all data) within one collection

Comment: @markus so does `Auth::user()->posts->with('images')->get()` worked?

Comment: @Rifki for your code i get: BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method with does not exist.

Comment: @markus sorry try with `load()` so it would be `Auth::user()->posts->load('images')`

Comment: @Rifki perfect!, now i see a relations array which contains the images! many thanks!

Comment: @markus Glad you got it works, and sorry I've lead you to wrong method when I said use `with()`

Answer (score 14):

Yes, use [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship.

posts model:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\postsimages');
}
```

user model

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\posts')->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
}

public function images()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\posts', 'App\postsimages');
}
```

then

```
$postimages = Auth::user()->images;
```

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, the 'App\postsimages' should be the first parameter